GTM previous Event Data Layer take along
I track the data layer information of a product for the event "add_to_cart" on the next step "begin_checkout" I have no readable data layer.
Is there a way to take the information/variables from the previous event/data layer to the next one?
I find no information on the web

Short answer: no. DL doesn't have the capabs to get values after it's reset, which is what it looks like.
Good news: there are a few ways to fix it.
The best way to fix it would be, of course, telling the front-end to maintain the DL properly and serve the product on the begin checkout and purchase confirmation.
If you're in one of those ugly situations where nobody cares enough to have developers involved, then you still can preserve it. Using something like local storage. You store the DL state in there on every add to cart and then analyze it once you're at the checkout.
This approach is problematic, however, for multiple reasons. Mostly that you'd have to keep track of all the product on every add to cart and remove from cart event. Also, there will be many artefacts that you won't cover.
Better approach would be parsing the existing state and DOM on the begin checkout and get your products from the page, functional local storage and the rest of the state.
